# I am trying to run an AppleScript on startup with launchd but with no results

Tags: applescript, launchd

The goal is to get a list of boot times for my computer that I can use to calculate power-outages at my workplace.

To do this I wrote a script that prints the current time when run and have created a plist in Library/LaunchDaemons that should run the script on start up.

My plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.power.log</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Users/labspecialist/Scripts/system_monitor.scpt</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

My AppleScript:

```
writeTextToFile(getTimeInHoursAndMinutes(), "/Users/labspecialist/Desktop/system_log")

on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile)
    try

        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string


        -- Open the file for writing
        set theOpenedFile to (open for access POSIX file theFile with write permission)

        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof


        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile


        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true

        -- Handle a write error
    on error

        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try

        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile



on getTimeInHoursAndMinutes()
    set theTime to ((current date) & return)
    return (theTime) as string
end getTimeInHoursAndMinutes
```

I expect this to create a text file on the desktop with the time of system boot however when I shutdown and restart it is not there. If I run the script in Script editor it works fine.

**Update**

In terminal I tried running the command `launchctl start local.power.log` Which received no errors but also did not run the script.

Comment: Are you aware the system already stores a log of startup times, boot times, wake/sleep cycles, etc.?  In Terminal, you can have a look at the output of `last | grep -Eiov "^$USER"` to see all reboot and shutdown times.  You can use `sysctl kern.waketime` to get the time the computer last woke up. And also check out the man page `man pmset` for accessing various logs relating to power management.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an AppleScript you have to add `osascript` as `Program` value and put the path to the script into the `ProgramArguments` array.

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>/Users/labspecialist/Scripts/system_monitor.scpt</string>
</array>
```

Other possible reasons why the script doesn't work

- Put the plist file into `~/Library/LaunchAgents` because it's not a daemon and it belongs to the user domain.
- Don't forget to `load` the agent.
- The file name of the plist file must be `local.power.log.plist`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would the ```osascript``` be a separate file from my .plist file?

Comment: `osascript` is a system binary file to compile and run AppleScripts on command line level.